# What suffixes are used to indicate jobs?

Tags: sufijos

What suffixes are used to indicate jobs? Please provide examples.

Comment: These are normally called "agent" or "agentive" suffixes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Common sufixes:**

Taken from ["Sufijos nominales en español", from Lucie Rossowová's Master Thesis, p. 30](http://is.muni.cz/th/145940/ff_m/diplomova_prace.pdf):

Noun suffixes denoting the "agent" of the action:

- -ero/-era (cocinero / cocinera)
- -dor/-dora (cazador / cazadora)
- -ante (cantante)
- -ista (deportista)

We could add some other examples (some of them may be "allomorphs" of another one):

- -or/-ora (captor / captora)       (may be allomorph with *-dor*)
- -or/-triz (actor / actriz)
- -in/-ina (bailarín / bailarina)

Derived from a masculine substantive:

- -isa (poeta → poetisa; sacerdote → sacerdotisa)        (is only used with feminine nouns)

Some roots take more than one suffix in order to "build" different meanings:

- -ante (cantante)
- -or (cantor)        (used at least in Chile to name a folklorist)

---

**Regional variations:**

- Andalusism:

  - -aor/-aora (bailaor / bailaora; cantaor / cantaora)        (in most cases is just the *-dor* suffix with its 'd' dropped.)

---

**Not directly related to jobs:**

- -logo/-loga (podólogo / podóloga; entomólogo / entomóloga)

  - This suffix relates to people who study or practice a science. As a side effect, they work on that field, but the suffix's main aim is not to emphasize the work done.
- -atra (pediatra; psiquiatra)

  - Someone who heals using some field of the medical science.

Comment: There is also _-ín_/_ina_ (e.g. _bailarín_) and _aor_ in the [Andalusisms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andalusian_Spanish#Influence) _bailaor_, _cantaor_, and _tocaor_.

Comment: @JaimeSoto: I've just included your comment because -in/-ina suffix is very important. Thanks!

Comment: Probably also _ólogo_: podólogo, odontólogo. _ico_:médico, físico, _atra_: fisiatra, pediatra,

Comment: @belisarius: I've just expanded my answer including the suffixes "-logo" and "-atra". The word "médico" doesn't have a suffix "-ico", as far as I know.